# Image upload from image tag

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, wcf

I did below working code

```
<input id="fuGraphic" type="file" name="file[]" value="" multiple />
```

Jquery Code

```
    function UploadImage(AdType) {

        //var fileData = file;
        fileData = document.getElementById("fuGraphic").files[0];
        var data = new FormData();

        var files = document.getElementById("fuGraphic").files;
        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {

            var fileData = files[i];
            var fileDataName = files[i].name;

            $.ajax({
                url: '../ProspectWorxService.svc/UploadFile?Id=' + strUniqID + '&AdType=' + AdType + '&fileName=' + fileData.name,
                type: 'POST',
                data: fileData,
                cache: false,
                dataType: 'json',
                processData: false, // Don't process the files
                contentType: "application/octet-stream", // Set content type to false as jQuery will tell the server its a query string request
                success: function (data) {

                    AddToTable(data.Id, strUniqID, data.ImageName);

                    //var trId = data.Id;
                    //var CampaignId = strUniqID;
                    //var fileName = data.ImageName;


                    //var strHtmlTable = '';
                    //strHtmlTable = '<tr id=' + trId + '><td><img src="uploadImage/' + CampaignId + '/' + fileName + '" width="80" height="44"></td><td>' + fileName + '</td><td><input type="button" name="btnDelete" value="Delete" onclick="DeleteTableRow(' + trId + ')" /></td></tr>';
                    //$('#tblImageListing').append(strHtmlTable);

                },
                error: function (data) {
                    alert('Some error Occurred!');
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

From this I able to get Image.

My question is, in html I have below code

```
<img src="images/ad160x600.png">
```

From FileUpload I sent 
files[i]

but now for

```
<img />
```

what I need to pass?

Comment: Sorry, what was your question again?

Comment: if file upload in html its working , but question is there is no file upload only image tag, for that how to upload it on server.